# How to cast from class type to interface

Tags: java

I have an interface which is implemented by few classes. Based on the full name of the class I want to initialize the class objects.

Interface,

```
public interface InterfaceSample{
}
```

Class files,

```
public class ABC implements InterfaceSample{
}
public class XYZ implements InterfaceSample{
}
```

A sample test class,

```
public class SampleManager{
public static InterfaceSample getInstance(String className) {
    InterfaceSample instance = null;
    try {
        instance =  (InterfaceSample) Class.forName(className);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return instance;
}

}
```

I am getting the following error,

```
 "Cannot cast from Class<capture#1-of ?> to InterfaceSample"
```

How can I initialize the classes based on its name.

Comment: What do you expect `Class.forName(...)` to return?

Comment: Do you really need cast there ? No right ?

Comment: @sisyphus, Class type. It was my stupid mistake. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
instance =  (InterfaceSample) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
```

remember to mark the method with:

```
throws Exception
```

because `newInstance()` is marked so as well (it throws `InstantiationException` and `IllegalAccessException` to be precise).

Comment: Please accept the answer as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You must invoke `newInstance()` on the class to get an instance.

```
public class SampleManager{
    public static InterfaceSample getInstance(String className) throws Exception {
        InterfaceSample instance = null;
        try {
            instance =  (InterfaceSample) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```